# What is the correct way to see and understand items in object explorer in relation with VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, object, reference

For the below EXCEL-VBA code it shows all are 9 means vbObject.

```
Sub whatwehave()

For Each ref In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References
    Debug.Print ref.Description; " -- "; ref.FullPath
Next

Debug.Print VarType(ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References)
Debug.Print VarType(ActiveWorkbook.VBProject)
Debug.Print VarType(ActiveWorkbook)

End Sub
```

Results are as below:

Visual Basic For Applications -- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6.DLL

Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library -- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE

Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library -- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FM20.DLL

9

9

9

Now if we search them ony by one in object explorer it shows below:

[image]
next
[image]
next
[image]

now question is in the object explorer Why references are not showing under VBProject ? The way we type dot "." and see the available methods/properties
in code window it does not exactly reflect that way in object explorer ? Or we should think both places will show information in a different way and interpret it from that angle ? What is the correct way to understand and explain this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility x.x` to access those :)

[image]

And then you will get what you are seeking :)

[image]

Comment: this starts 1 more question ....without adding this reference how those methods/objects are accessible to my code

Comment: In my opinion (i could be wrong), those members are available to you because of the Excel Class. And the Class may not have all the `information` about a particular member. In this case the information which we seek is saved in the `VBE6EXT.OLB` which is `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility x.x`